# Ошибка Selenium

Tags: selenium

Как спарсить цену предмета?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

url='https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/Recoil%20Case'
options=webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe',options=options)


try:
    driver.get(url=url)
    normal_price=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="market_commodity_forsale"]/span[2]').text
    print(normal_price)


except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)


finally:
    driver.close()
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: А в чем ошибка?

Comment: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="market_commodity_forsale"]/span[2]"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Видимо селениум пытается найти элемент до того, как страница прогрузилась.
Попробуйте ожидать появление элемента.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

url = 'https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/Recoil%20Case'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

try:
    driver.get(url)
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
        lambda x: x.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="market_commodity_forsale"]/span[2]'))
    normal_price = element.text
    print(normal_price)
except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
finally:
    driver.close()
    driver.quit()
```

https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.wait

Comment: О господи, как я мог забыть про это, спасибо